# Azure Durable Functions 500 502 504 Error

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, http-error, azure-durable-functions

I’m having an issue running durable functions in Azure. The durable functions run correctly on my local computer, but for some reason is not running on Azure.

I’ve followed the steps in the [Python Durable Functions quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode) to create a "hello world" durable function, test the function locally, and deploy the function app to Azure. However, I’m receiving a 500 Internal Server Error, 502 Bad Gateway, or 504 Gateway Time-out when sending an HTTP request to the URL endpoint.

[image: 500 Internal Server Error]
[image: 502 Bad Gateway]
[image: 504 Gateway Time-out]

Python durable function app configs:

- Local Python version: Python 3.8.5
- Durable functions runtime stack/Python version: Python 3.8
- Durable functions runtime version: ~3
- Durable functions host.json extensionBundles version: V1 or [1.*,
  2.0.0)
- App Service plan operating system: Linux

Thanks!

---

Update and **solution** April 27, 2021:

The root cause of the issue appears to be  that the App Service Plan is oversubscribed with more than 31 Apps, this is resulting in 100% CPU consumption and greater than 80% utilization.

[image: Oversubscribed]

To solve this, reduce the number of Apps currently running on the App Service Plan, as well as scale up the current App Service Plan or create additional App Service Plan.

Comment: Please consider adding more information about your setup by editing your question. Can you describe the steps you followed from the referenced link? This could help others to answer your question.

Comment: Hi John, I followed the tutorial to create a "hello world" durable function, test the function locally, and finally deploy the function app to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Errors with the beginning of '5' mean server-side problems, so just give the server side error code is not enough:

[image]

Please go to the application insights, and run `requests`, find the operation which is failed:

[image]

Copy the operation id:

[image]

Then run the `exceptions`:

Search by the operation id, and you will get the error log(The details of the error).